# For positive random variables, $X_n \stackrel{p}{\to} X$ and $E(X_n) \to E(X)$ implies $E|X_n-X|\to 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $X,X_1,X_2\ldots$ be positive random variables. Suppose $X_n \stackrel{p}{\to} X$ and $E(X_n) \to E(X)$. Show that $E|X_n-X|\to 0$.

I observed certain things. For example, it is enough to prove for the case when $X_n \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} X$ due to sub-sequence criterion. However still I cannot exploit the condition well enough.

Comment: Is it also given that $E(X_n),E(X)< \infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have to assume $X \in L^1$; otherwise the claim does in general not hold. (Just consider $[0,1]$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure and $X_n(x) := x^{-1+1/n}$. Then the assumptions are satisfied but, since $X = x^{-1} \notin L^1$, we cannot expect $\|X_n-X\|_{L^1} \to 0$.)

---

**Hint:** Apply Fatous Lemma to $$Y_n := X_n+X-|X_n-X|.$$